# ssh-agent key timeout with screen or tmux on bastion host

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, tmux, ssh-agent

Normally I have ssh-agent running, I ssh to my bastion host then open a tmux session and connect to other boxes through that.  Key forwarding works for any sessions that I open from that point forward.

If I resume my tmux session after closing terminal, sleeping my laptop, whatever, my key forwarding on my bastion sessions still work, as does forwarding on any *new* sessions.  Existing ones don't work, though.

I have a little thing in my bashrc that keeps key forwarding working when I resume tmux, but I am having trouble figuring out how to get it to keep working for sessions open within tmux.

For example, I have bastion01, dbhost01, dbhost02, webhost01, and webhost02.

If I open a connection to bastion01, start tmux there, and then connect to dbhost01 and webhost01 forwarding works.  If I close that connection, reconnect and attach my existing tmux session, then add connections to dbhost02 and webhost02, key forwarding works on the 02 boxes, but does not on the 01.

Please help!

Answer (score 12):

Each time you ssh into `bastion01`, a different socket is opened to handle the key forwarding. You can see the filename in the environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. When you start `tmux`, the value of that environment variable is included in `tmux`'s global environment, which is inherited by any shells started in that session.

Now, when you reconnect to `bastion01` later, a different socket is allocated to handle your key forwarding (since it's a new ssh session). You can see this by examining the value of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` before you re-attach to your `tmux` session and after. In order for key forwarding to work inside `tmux`, you need to update the value of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` inside `tmux` to the name of the socket being used by the current ssh session.

A quick-and-dirty way to do this is to write a short script that will save this new value to a file, and execute that inside any `tmux` window where you will be `ssh`-ing from.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" > ~/.auth_ssh
```

Execute that script as soon as you ssh into `bastion01`, but before you re-attach to your tmux session. Then, before you try to ssh anywhere from inside `tmux`, run the following:

```
source ~/.auth_ssh
```

Each `tmux` window has its own environment, so you'll need to run that in each window where you try to run ssh. For simplicity, you can alias ssh to do it for you:

```
alias ssh="source ~/.auth_ssh; ssh"
```

Note: this is a gross oversimplification of a script we use at work to update the SSH authorization information. If it doesn't work quite right, I hope this at least gives you enough information to google a better solution (or someone else posts a better solution here).

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner and more robust solution, adapted from https://superuser.com/a/439006/161249

On the remote, in `~/.ssh/rc`:

```bash
# to reconnect ssh-agent through a disconnected session
if [ -n "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}" ]; then
    ln -snf "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}" "${HOME}/.ssh/tmux_ssh_auth_sock" # symlink read in ~/.tmux.conf
fi

# vim: ft=bash
```

and in `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
# to reconnect ssh-agent through a disconnected session
set-environment -g 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK' ~/.ssh/tmux_ssh_auth_sock # symlink set by ~/.ssh/rc
```

Quoting @Arcege:

> The problem with using the 'alias' solution ... is that the processes running in screen now have the same SSH_AUTH_SOCK value on the remote side.