# Can I re-attach SSH key forwarding through a disconnected Screen session?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ssh-agent key timeout with screen or tmux on bastion host](https://superuser.com/questions/438651/ssh-agent-key-timeout-with-screen-or-tmux-on-bastion-host)

I have a laptop on which I have pageant (the PuTTy SSH key agent) running.  If I ssh to a system and launch screen, the ssh key forwarding works properly.

However, if I disconnect from that screen session, log off, then later reconnect -- the key forwarding doesn't work any more.  I am presuming that this is because when I reconnect the key forwarding is set up on different ports for the new ssh session than was the old one.

Is there a way to teach an individual screen window to reconnect to the agent forwarding so that I can use my key to forward again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution is a bit more robust.  Put this in your .bash_profile on the remote side.

```
if [ -z "${STY}" -a -t 0 ]; then
    reattach () {
        if [ -n "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}" ]; then
            ln -snf "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}" "${HOME}/.ssh/agent-screen"
            SSH_AUTH_SOCK="${HOME}/.ssh/agent-screen" export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
        fi
        exec screen -A -D -RR ${1:+"$@"}
    }
fi
```

Then I use `reattach` instead of `screen`.  This could be done using `command screen -A ${1:+"$@"}` and 'screen' instead of 'reattach'.

The problem with using the 'alias' solution in the answer by @David Mackintosh is that the processes running in screen now have the same SSH_AUTH_SOCK value on the remote side.  Think of the following scenerio.

- local: start SSH agent getting `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` value
- local: SSH to remote, setting new `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` value on remote
- remote: start `screen` or `tmux`, using SSH_AUTH_SOCK
- remote: create shell, which inherits SSH_AUTH_SOCK from `screen`
- remote: detach from screen and log out
- local: SSH to remote, setting *new* `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` value on remote
- remote: reattach to screen session, which still has *old* `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` value

The trick is to get the processes running inside screen to use the new value.  You can do that by repointing a symlink to the current `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` each time you call `screen` (for new or reattached session).

Comment: A cleaner adaptation of this solution: https://superuser.com/a/1790651/161249 that sets the symlink in `~/.ssh/rc` and the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` env in `~/.tmux.conf`

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a duplicate of: [ssh-agent key timeout with screen or tmux on bastion host](https://superuser.com/questions/438651/ssh-agent-key-timeout-with-screen-or-tmux-on-bastion-host)

The solution:

- add to your .bash_profile:

  echo "export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" > ~/.ssh/auth_sock
- add to your .bashrc:

  alias ssh="source ~/.ssh/auth_sock ; ssh"

This seems to work so far for me.

Comment: I wrote the answer for the question you linked to. Good to hear it works for you; I hadn't tested it, and I wasn't sure it was complete enough! :)